# How to correctly use getText() in Android Studio, to get user input?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gettext

I have been trying to get a simple user input, but GetText() throws me a "Cannot resolve method 'GetText()'" I have been trying to find a fix for a while, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class IzmeruNoteiksana extends AppCompatActivity {

int length;
float mass;

EditText theMass;
EditText theLength;

Button submitButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_izmeru_noteiksana);

        theMass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.theMass);
        theLength = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.theLength);

        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mass = Float.valueOf(mass.GetText().toString());
                length = Integer.valueOf(length.GetText().toString());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: you have named your `TextField` as `theLength` and you are calling `GetText()` on `length`. Also, it's `getText()` and not `GetText()` You have a typo. Please recheck.

Comment: Oh god, I can't believe I didn't spot that typo. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You've coded :-

```
length = Integer.valueOf(length.GetText().toString());
```

You should instead be using :-

```
length = Integer.valueOf(theLength.getText().toString());
```

i.e. you want the text from the EditText **theLength**, not **length** (an Integer object) which doesn't have a getText method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this did not seem to fix the issue!

Comment: @ComicalChicken there is no method known as `GetText()`. You'll get a red squiggly line error.

Answer (score 0):

Tou have to do it like this, on button click

```
String strMassVal = theMass.getText().toString().trim();
String strLenghVal = theLength.getText().toString().trim();
if(!strMassVal.isEmpty()){
mass = Float.parseFloat(strMassVal);
}
if(!strLengthVal.isEmpty()){
length = Integer parseInt(strLengthVal);
}
```